# Azure CosmosDB scaling globally

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've seen the videos about Azure CosmosDB scaling around the world by clicking on a map, which is neat. But in those demos, they connect directly to the database from a client.

It's my understanding that allowing a client (like wpf desktop program) to directly access a database is a bad idea. It should be behind a web api that we control access to.

So for scaling globally, I don't really need lots of areas where users are, I need the same datacenter that's hosting the api.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but... imagine if you had your API (and/or web app) running in multiple regions, and then each region's instances connecting to a specific Cosmos DB instance which is local to the API/web-app instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting article in the docs refering to [Multi-master database architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/multi-region-writers) that will be useful.

Basically, if you are going to expose a Web API and clients will connect to it instead of the database, you want the Web API as closer to the database as possible (that's when global replication comes into play).

To transparently connect the client to the closest API, you can use [Traffic Manager's Geographic routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#geographic).